# Publishing Salesforce Customer Community on a custom domain

Tags: community, custom-domain

Can you please help me in understanding what would be the required steps for pointing a domain like https://mycompany.com/Customers to a custom SFDC community login page? I suspect there is more than just a simple URL redirect in this case.

We would like to have the landing page of the customer community as https://mycompany.com/Customers. We have already built the login page which is a branded VF page with OOB SFDC community authentication.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated .

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a custom URL under the community site.

Go the site name under Sites [in my case the partner portal (community site)]

[image]

Click on site name -- you will find a section called Custom URL

[image]

In the next step you will need to give domain name and path.

Answer (score 0):

If you choose to use Site.com pages instead of tabs, the home Page selected for your community Site.com site is the first page customers see when they access the community.

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Hi Varun - I am not using site.com. We have built a custom community login VF page something like this https://xyz-dev.cs14.force.com/abcdef/login . What I want is when someone goes to https://mycompany.com/Customers it should show the custom login page and the subsequent pages after login shouldn't show force.com address in the URLS.